# Global variable in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, json, global-variables, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel Service Providers and i recently run into a problem. I'm trying to access an variable from a Service Provider in all views (global). The variable comes in json format.
Here is my ServiceProvider

```
<?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

  class ExternalVarServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
      /**
       * Bootstrap the application ExternalVarServiceProvider.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {
          $url = "json-source-url";
          $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
          $var = $json["array_index"];
          //var should be global to all blade files, app.blade.php is main templ
          View::share( 'app', 'var' );
      }

      /**
       * Register the application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
          //
      }
  }
```

Thank you for reading, Pat :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are doing it right but you just need to change this line in your service provider from

```
View::share( 'app', 'var' );
```

to

```
View::share( 'app', $var );
```

and in your view you can use it like this

```
{{$app}}
```

you can also pass an array in your service provider like this :

```
\View::share( ['app'=> $var,'app2'=>$var2] );
```

Note that according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) the share method accepts key and value ,so **app** isn't the view name its a **key** of your shared value

Comment: thank you, i now realizes that share takes var name and then value, not view-to-share-to then value. Thanks mate :)