# How to declare global variables available to all Blade Files?

Tags: laravel

I have products in a database that are essentially used on every single page. Instead of having to query the database, something like this:

```
$products = DB::table("products")->get();
```

And then passing it into view:

```
return view("site.products", array(
   'products' => $products,
));
```

I don't want to do this for every view. Instead, I want $products to be available to ALL templates by default... so that I can do this:

```
@foreach ($products as $product) 
 ... etc
```

How would I declare it in a global way to achieve this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#service-injection

Comment: Did you tried using sessions as a global variable. Or use a package called session.

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45807512/global-variable-in-laravel-blade

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371540/global-variable-in-laravel-8

Comment: Or this? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recommended way of doing this is to add a middleware that you apply to all the routes that you want to affect.

**Middleware**

```
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class GlobalVariablesMiddleware
{
    $myVariable = "Value For Everyone";
    View::share(['globalValue' => $myVariable]);
}
```

Add it to your kernel.php in the Http folder

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'myMiddleware' => \App\Http\Middleware\ GlobalVariablesMiddleware::class,
];
```

Once this is setup, you can easily apply it to individual routes or grouped ones to achieve what you are looking for

```
// Routes that will have the middleware    
Route::middleware(['myMiddleware'])->group(function () {
    
        // My first route that will have the global value
        Route::resource('/profile', App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class);

        // My second route that will have the global value
        Route::resource('/posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);
    });
```

By doing it this way, you can easily control the data in the future if you would chose not to have the data global.

Answer (score 2):

You can add below code in the boot method of `AppServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    if (!$this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $products = DB::table("products")->get();
        \View::share('products', $products);
    }
}
```

Read more from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)